# Using QTextToSpeech with winrt engine stops playing speech after one word

Tags: c++, qt, text-to-speech, sapi

I have a C++ program using Qt 6.5.2. I'm trying to use its `QTextToSpeech` class on Windows 11.

It works fine when I set the engine to "sapi", but when I set it to the higher quality "winrt" engine, it stops playing the speech after less than a second.

Here's the code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTextToSpeech>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextToSpeech * speech = new QTextToSpeech();
    speech->setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::LatinScript, QLocale::UnitedStates));
    speech->setEngine("winrt");
    speech->say("Mary had a little lamb, its fleece was white as snow. How did that sound?");

    return app.exec();
}
```

It says the word "*Mary*", then just stops. The `QTextToSpeech` state remains set to 1 (playing), and it reports no error. It just stops playing.

I tried using the lower quality "sapi" engine, and the full text was spoken.

How can I solve this?

Comment: SAPI has its own event loop if you don’t provide one.   WinRT doesn’t.  What happens if you move your code inside Qt’s event loop?

Comment: @EricBrown I originally had the code inside Qt's event loop, in a slot method that handles a button press. That's when I first ran into this problem. I tried moving it out into  main() to eliminate any other possible factors. Thank you for the suggestion though.